# printing array generated from fgetcsv is throwing undefined index

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I want to get data from csv file having header row. I want to use the data using header row index. But it is showing undefined index. The code is as follows:

```
$count = 0;
$total = 0;

if ( false === $handle = fopen('hw_product.csv', 'r') )
    throw new Exception('File open failed.');

$headers = fgetcsv($handle);

while ( false !== $fields = fgetcsv($handle) ) {
    $fields = array_combine($headers, $fields);
    $total++;
    $p_id = $fields['id_product'];
    $sku = $fields['sku'];
    $url = $fields['url_key'];

    $query = "UPDATE hw_product_lang SET link_rewrite = '$url' WHERE id_product = $p_id AND id_lang = 1";
    if(mysqli_query($link,$query)){
        $count++;
    }  
}

fclose($handle);
echo $count." rows processed out of ".$total;
```

Please help me what i am missing. Thanks

Comment: Which field is giving the undefined index?

Comment: all the 3 fields.

Comment: A quick check would be to use `print_f($fields);` to see what values are set.

Comment: Its giving `Array ( [id_product] => 2 [sku] => 092-1000 [url_key] => back-splash )` and so on